# Convert C# X509Certificate2 to java

Tags: java, certificate

I can use c# to import a .p12 certificate into windows personal store by the statements below:

```
X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2("certificate.p12" ,"p@ssword");
X509Store store2 = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store2.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
store2.Add(cert2);
store2.Close();
```

I need to rewrite my code in JAVA. How to port these code to Java?? Thank you

Comment: KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("certificate.p12"),"p@ssword".toCharArray()); but seems not work...

Comment: What do you mean with "seems not to work".  If you want us to help you, you better provide as much details you can.  Please update your question.

Comment: To check the result, I go to IE-->Internet Options-->Contents-->Certificate. After execute the C# code i mentioned in the question. I can see the certificate has imported to Personal Store. However, the Java code I mentioned in the comment doesn't import the cert. what I want to do is to import the p12 certificate to the Windows Certificate store.